# Сохранение позиции скролла React при переходе между диалогами React (Next)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, frontend, nextjs

Никак не могу найти информацию как сохранить положение скролла при переходах между диалогами  как в вк или телеграме

Например

1. зашёл диалог (первично подгрузились сообщения и проскролилось вниз)
2. Поскролил вверх
3. Перешел в другой диалог
4. Вернулся обратно и всё осталось на своих местах а не ушло вниз или верх (то есть небыло первичной подгрузки и тд и тп всё сохранено в памяти)

Пытаюсь реализовать но пока что идея лишь в сохранении состояния в (state, ref, и тд)

Comment: Подумайте над localStorage, но то что это куда то надо сохранять, верная мысль

Comment: проблема скорее не в месте куда сохранять а как это делать 

если я буду каждую секунду обрабатывать сохранение всё лагать будет 

мне нужен механизм который будет это делать точечно и временно

Comment: Сохраняйте это на стороне клиента. Тогда это будет не каждую секунду. И у каждого клиента будет своя настройка.

Comment: Мы друг друга не правильно поняли видимо.....
Я на фронте на клинте хочу реализовать сохранение прокрутки между переключениями диалогов сообщений, сохранять я буду в оперативной памяти (временно) но как это сделать грамотно я не особо понимаю  

кроме как поставить обработчик событий и каждое событие оно не сможет обрабатывать (а при скролле это очень много событий за секунду) 

ставить таймаут чтобы отследить только конце прокрутки я не особо хочу - чувствуется что есть что то ещё

Comment: @Pasha1neo  а что если сохранять в sessionStorage ну или куда тебе удобнее. Сохраняться оно будет только при нажатие кнопки назад или при переходе на другую страницу. Для реализации подобного есть eventListener unload  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event . Попробуй  если не получиться реализовать с отслеживанием скролла лагать не должно проверь